# Change default installation location and Create a desktop shortcut link in Install4j

Tags: install4j

I am using Install4j to create installer for my app.

1. I want to change the default installation folder location to "My Documents" folder. I am trying to do it from "Installation location"" screen. But not getting the result.Can anyone please tell me that which things i need to change/edit ?
2. I want to create a desktop shortcut link icon. I am trying to do it using "Add a Desktop link" action under "Desktop Integration"" category. But not getting the expected result. I am sure than I am missing something but don't know which part. So can anyone please suggest me the whole operation to add a desktop link ?

I am not an expert on Install4j but have the basic knowledge. I have searched on google and checked the previous threads on stackoverflow but didn't get my expected result.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to change the default installation folder location to "My Documents" folder.

In the "startup" node of your installer, add a "Run script" action with the script:

```
File docsDir = WinFileSystem.getSpecialFolder(SpecialFolder.DOCS, false);
File installationDir = new File(docsDir, "myApp");
context.setInstallationDirectory(installationDir);
return true;
```

> I want to create a desktop shortcut link icon. I am trying to do it using "Add a Desktop link" action

Probably the file does not exist yet. Move the action after the "Install files" action on the "Installation" screen.